# List of all html entity chars mapping

Tags: html, entity, character

where can I find mega list of all html entity characters?
http://www.w3schools.com does not cover all.
E.g. &# 145; &# 146; &# 147; &# 148; (values of these entities: ' & ")
are not included on this website.

Comment: "mega" as in 1 million? I doubt there is that many... I could be wrong though

Answer (score 2):

For HTML there is a limited number of named entities (such as `&amp;`), and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML) and [the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/sgml/entities.html) have lists of these.

Then there is the HTML syntax for a Unicode character reference (such as `&#145;`), and for these you really just need to look at the [Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.1.0/).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on HTML version, and a comprehensive answer would be rather long. But briefly, any Unicode character that is allowed in HTML (this depends on HTML version) can be written using a character reference of the form `&#n;` where `n` is is Unicode number in decimal, and also using `&#xh;` where `h` is is Unicode number in decimal. A limited set (a few hundred characters) can also be written as entity references like `&ndash;`, but their browser support varies – HTML5 novelties in this respect should be avoided, and only the [HTML 4.01 entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html) have virtually universal support (in HTML; not necessarily in genuine XHTML).

The reference `&#145;` is undefined, though by HTML5 drafts there is strictly defined [error handling](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tokenization.html#tokenizing-character-references) that maps it to LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (as browsers generally do). There’s no reason to use it, but some HTML generating software emits such references.